# SQL declare statement error on hostinger server

Tags: mysql

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dIncr DATE = '2000-01-01' dEnd DATE = '2100-01-01' CREATE TABLE _Dates ( d ' at line 2

error coming on hostinger server my sql query below

```
CREATE TABLE _Dates (
  d DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (d)
)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2000-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = '2100-01-01'

WHILE ( @dIncr < @dEnd )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO _Dates (d) VALUES( @dIncr )
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr )
END
```

Comment: Try putting semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: not working with that

Answer (score 1):

You may need a stored procedure. Also, the DATEADD function in MariaDB appears to be DATE_ADD(). Expect your procedure call to take a while.

```
CREATE TABLE _Dates (
  d DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (d)
);
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addDates()
BEGIN
    DECLARE dIncr DATE DEFAULT '2000-01-01';
    DECLARE dEnd DATE DEFAULT '2100-01-01';
    WHILE (dIncr < dEnd) DO
        INSERT INTO _Dates(d)
        VALUES (dIncr);
        SET dIncr = DATE_ADD(dIncr, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
CALL addDates();
```

Comment: I think this answer is basically correct.  The code in the question is really T-SQL code and not MySQL code.

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot.. onlu hitch is it inserts rows, but i need columns as the dates how do i do that?

Comment: Actually i want to add the first row with all dates as columns which are the headers row. The data will get added into individual rows later

Comment: I have deleted all routines.. i now need the code to ass all dates as columns in the headrer row.. pl help

Comment: I am glad to have helped with the original question. If you are trying to create dates as columns, you may want to modify your question or begin a new one.